# Can you build a CSS file for Google Apps Script for Google Sheets from data from the sheet itself?

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a sign-in form, which passes the sign-in data to a Google Spreadsheet. The form uses CSS and Jquery to build the UI and interactivity of the elements. The CSS file uses CSS variables, but those are still hard-coded into the `style.html` file itself. I'd like to pull the style information from a Settings sheet in the Google Spreadsheet itself.

To do this, I'm trying a file called `customcss.html` which, instead of a style file, is a script file that writes a `<style>` tag for jquery to append to the head element once the page is loaded. The `customcss.html` file looks like:

```
<script>
var sL = "<style>";
sL += ":root { --body-bg-color: " + google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnVal).getNamedRangeVal("body.bg.color") + "; ";
sL += "--num-text-color: " + google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnVal).getNamedRangeVal("num.text.color") + "; ";
sL += "--num-bg-color: " + google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnVal).getNamedRangeVal("num.bg.color") + "; ";
.
.
.
sL += "} </style>";
$("head").append(sL);
</script>
```

In order to pull data from the Sheet, the function `getNamedRangeVal` is called, which finds the defined name range passed to the function and reads the appropriate value in the cell:

```
function getNamedRangeVal(nR) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetURL);
  var ws = ss.getRangeByName(nR).getValue();
  return ws;
}
```

Since what is returned by `getNamedRangeVal` is the data I need, I need the success handler `returnVal` to be able to return a value (since a function called via  `google.script.run.` returns `void`); `returnVal` is pretty basic - it simply turns around and passes back whatever it's passed:

```
function returnVal(v) {
  return v;
}
```

**The problem is** when the script runs, it does append the appropriate `<style>` tag, but all variable values are `undefined`, which from my initial investigation appears to be because of the async nature of the `google.script.run` call.

So what can I do to get the data from the sheet to the callback function to build the CSS script?

Comment: You need to rewrite your script so you get all data needed from Sheets in one call of `google.script.run`, then on callback insert your styles with returned values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and solution:

Calling [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) in the client-side (i.e., web browser) code starts the specified server-side Apps Script function. The client-side function continues execution immediately without waiting for the server-side function to complete. Often, the client-side function will simply end at this point.

When the server-side function eventually completes, the function specified by [withSuccessHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) or [withFailureHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withfailurehandlerfunction) is started automatically, depending on whether the server-side function completed successfully or threw an error.

Therefore, as [Kos said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69184031/can-you-build-a-css-file-for-google-apps-script-for-google-sheets-from-data-from#comment122280598_69184031), you should move the CSS building to the function called by `withSuccessHandler`.

#### Alternatively, use templates:

Another way to dynamically build the CSS would be to use [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates), which allows executing server-side code directly, without using `google.script.run`, but via [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets). That is a valid option if you want to bring a small amount of static data to the client-side when the page loads (see [Load data asynchronously, not in templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates)).

See a simplified example in which the color for the `div` elements is brought from the server with the printing-scriplets (`<?= ?>`):

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div {
        color: <?= myColor("color") ?>;
        background-color: <?= myColor("background-color") ?>;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>THIS SHOULD BE COLORED</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  const output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
  return output;
}

function myColor(prop) {
  switch (prop) {
    case "color":
      return "blue";
    case "background-color":
      return "red";
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh! Didn't even think of putting it in as a scriptlet!

Can a scriptlet have a parameter passed to it? ```myColor("body.bg.color")```, ```myColor("num.text.color")```, etc.?

Comment: @JeffWhite Sure you can provide parameters to a server-side function used in templates. Take a look at my updated code snippet.